# How to set Dynamically UITableView height in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to set Tableview height dynamically like in android. i tried with following code, but its not working.

```
 tblHeightConstraint.constant = downSelectionTbl.contentSize.height
```

see this below link i tired upvote answers even though its not resolved my issue.

> [iOS: Dynamically set UITableView height in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794557/ios-dynamically-set-uitableview-height-in-swift)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tblHeightConstraint.constant = downSelectionTbl.contentSize.height
}
```

Comment: @ram for alternate solution check this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content/48623673#48623673

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell this function working like a charm.. Thq @venkat